# Script organization patterns (MVC + jQGrid)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm building a MVC web app with heavy use of ajax loaded partial views containing jQGrids and javascripts. Many of the partial views contains only 2 div tags and the rest is javascripts.

Using script tags makes the general page structure much more logic to me, because the javascripts are the content of the page as I see it.

However there are also *small utilityfunctions, like formatting functions,* used by jQGrid and I'm starting to see an increasing risk of scripts with the same name performing almost identical tasks.

Example of formatting function:

```
    function primaryRoleFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        switch (cellvalue) {
            case "1":
                return "<%= Resource.PRIMARY %>";

            default:
                break;
        }

        return "";
    };
```

At first I saw the formatting functions as belonging to the closest grid, especially since there might be other grids having a formatting function with the same name but with some small differences in the code.

I load two or more grids at the same time, it seems that javascript is smart enough to use the script defined in the current script block if there's a name clash so there's no problem yet beyond the nagging thoughs, "is this the best way of doing this?".

There's also *scripts for ajax-loading and displaying jQuery dialogs* from grid actions. I'm thinking that the scripts will add up over time.

**Should I just keep the scripts where they are used or should I try to build a script library of some kind?**

If I should move them out to script files, what's a smart way of partitioning the functions (names, classes, files...)?
If I move them out, would they be considered more unobtrusive as this type of page is already loaded by ajax itself and consisting to 95% of javascripts?

*I realize there are **similar** questions but I didn't find any suiting answer. If there's a problem with this, I'll delete it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Object Literals](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace)

The simplest way to avoid unnecessary pollution of the global namespace is to place related functions in an object literal:

```
var Formatter = {

    primaryRoleFormatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        switch (cellvalue) {
            case "1":
                return "<%= Resource.PRIMARY %>";
            default:
                break;
        }
        return "";
    },

    someOtherFormatter: function() {

    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
Formatter.primaryRoleFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
Formatter.someOtherFormatter();
```

This results in one property on the global object instead of one for each function you define.

### [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)

Or you could hide things with function scope:

```
var Formatter = (function() {

    function FormatterCtor() {
        // instance-ish level func
        this.onePerInstance = function() {}
    }

    // not accessible from the outside; not in the global namespace
    function privateFunction() {}

    // class-ish level func
    FormatterCtor.oneShared = function() {}

    return FormatterCtor;

})(); // self-executing
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var fmt = new Formatter();
fmt.onePerInstance();
```

In either case, you end up with just one variable in the global namespace, which is a win.

Comment: Upvoted. I had to move the Formatter var in front of the grid this time but it works nicely.